# Prolog, I want to get 2 different values from list and all the others to another list

Tags: list, prolog

Let's say I have `list(A,X,Y,R)` and i want to get `X` and `Y` two values from `A` that are different and all the other `A` values go to `R`.

How could I do this ?

Examples

```
?- list([],X,Y,R). false.
?- list([1],X,Y,R). false.
?- list([1,2],X,Y,R). X=1, Y=2, R=[];
X=2, Y=1, R=[].
?- list([1,1],X,Y,R). X=1, Y=1, R=[];
X=1, Y=1, R=[].
?- list([1,2,3],X,Y,R). X=1, Y=2, R=[3];
X=1, Y=3, R=[2];
X=2, Y=1, R=[3];
X=2, Y=3, R=[1]; X=3, Y=1, R=[2]; X=3, Y=2, R=[1].
```

Comment: Could you provide some example/s of the desired behavior?

Comment: I added it above as an edit, hope this helps!

Comment: Okey, just one more question: could there be repeated values in A? For example `[1,2,3,1]` ?

Comment: Preferably not, but if it is not possible I could find an alternative for that later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, here you have a general solution. I've tried it in SWI-prolog, but if any predicate doesn't work for you at least you can look for an equivalent:

```
list([A,B|T], X, Y, T) :- 
    permutation([A,B], [X, Y]).
list([A,B|T], X, Y, [D|R]) :- 
    permutation([C, D], [A,B]),
    list([C|T], X, Y, R).
```

Breakdown:

- Base case: `X` and `Y` are the two first elements in any order. `R` would be the tail of the list.
- Recursive case: From the first two elements, pick one (`D`) and remove it from the list before trying  again, then add it to `R`.

It passes the examples you've given, although the solutions aren't retrieved in the same order as you wrote.

Comment: I too use SWI-Prolog but the last 2 examples don't work for me 
?- list([1,1],X,Y,R). % returns false
?- list([1,2,3],X,Y,R). % it shows my R list as empty :/ 

Amazing and fast work tho !

Comment: Okey, give me a second

Comment: Now it works. I didn't see your example with [1,1]